# MemoryError in Python 2.7 when iterating over a large file word by word

Tags: python, iterator, out-of-memory

I need to read a large file multiple times and need access to the total number of words in the file. I've implemented a wrapper class that contains an iterator, a copy of the iterator (to reset the iterator) and its length:

```
Class DataWrapper(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data, self.copy = itertools.tee(data)
    self.length = None

  def __iter__(self):
    return self.data

  def next(self):
    return self.data.next()

  def reset(self):
    self.data, self.copy = itertools.tee(self.copy)

  def __len__(self):
    if self.length is None:
      self.data, dcopy = itertools.tee(self.data)
      self.length = sum(1 for x in dcopy)
    return self.length
```

I then create the actual file reading iterator and start iterating:

```
def my_iter(fname):
  with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      for word in line.split():
        yield word

dw = DataWrapper(my_iter("large_file.txt"))
for w in dw:
    pass
```

For some reason though, I get a `MemoryError` while iterating:

File "my_script.py", line 164, in my_iter
   for line in f:
MemoryError

Since this does not happen without the wrapper, I assume [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is to blame. But is there another way to reset the iterator?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the details of the error. On which line does it happen?

Comment: I agree -- this is probably the work of `itertools.tee`.  As far as I an come up with, there is no way to reset this iterator without keeping a cache of the data.  However, if you abstract around the file object rather than the iterator, you can `.seek` back to particular file locations ...

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee): "This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on how much temporary data needs to be stored). In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee()."

Comment: there is also [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) which may or may not be helpful ...

Comment: @Alex: Well list() is not really an option here either, since the file is very large.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen What do you need the copy for? This seems doable without the custom class.

Comment: @Alex: I use the copy to reset the iterator, as I need to iterate many times over the file...

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen why not just open a new file handle and create a new iterator?

Comment: @Alex: You have a point :-). I guess I was too fixated on keeping the same flow for both streamed and in-memory reading. And re-reading the file was of course not an option, whereas recreating the iterator is... Let me test this and get back to you.

Comment: @Alex: seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that if the data is only read once, and must be iterated multiple times, it has to been kept in memory. If the file is large enough to exhaust the memory you will end with a MemoryError. Here the `itertool.tee` is indeed the culprit, even if IMHO it is not to blame for it because it has no other way to do ;-)

If you cannot keep the data in memory, the only foolproof way would be to open a new file handler for each iterator - provided the OS and file system allow it. That way the memory will only contain one buffer and one line per iterator instead of the whole file.